# Authenticate web API 2 from cordova app with Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-web-api2

have a Cordova app with Onsen framework, I want to authenticate my Web Api 2 with Facebook login or with SQLServer Database users table.

The Facebook login works successfully with the Cordova APP, I get a token from Facebook and the logged user, how can I secure my Web API with this way?

I store FB access token in session in my cordova app and send that key to the web api, and the web api stores that key in a temp table and compare it with the sent key from the app but I think this is not the right way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I'm in the same boat as you, only I've attempted to tackle Google Plus as the external login provider first. Did you get anywhere with this? 

I've got an authenticated ASP.NET Web API and I suppose we need to know which URL to hit to authenticate with an external provider  and what data we need to provide - and do we get that data from the Cordova plugin on successful login? As a side note, I'm using Ionic which is built on Cordova.

Comment: I connect to FB graph url, and provide FB access token. If the graph returns data that means a successful login